# Last character of numeric string being removed, how to fix this problem in C?

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to solve a problem with replacing letters with numbers. The user will enter a string, in case there are letters, I must substitute the corresponding number, and in case there are `* # -` symbols, I must simply remove them.

However, I am facing an issue. When the user types only a numeric string, the last character of this string is being removed, which cannot happen. This can only happen if there are letters or symbols in the string.

**Source**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void alterChars(char phrase[])
{
    int i, dashes = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; phrase[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (phrase[i] == 'A' || phrase[i] == 'B' || phrase[i] == 'C')
        {
            phrase[i] = '2';
        }

        if (phrase[i] == 'D' || phrase[i] == 'E' || phrase[i] == 'F')
        {
            phrase[i] = '3';
        }

        if (phrase[i] == 'G' || phrase[i] == 'H' || phrase[i] == 'I')
        {
            phrase[i] = '4';
        }

        if (phrase[i] == 'J' || phrase[i] == 'K' || phrase[i] == 'L')
        {
            phrase[i] = '5';
        }

        if (phrase[i] == 'M' || phrase[i] == 'N' || phrase[i] == 'O')
        {
            phrase[i] = '6';
        }
        
        if (phrase[i] == 'P' || phrase[i] == 'Q' || phrase[i] == 'R' || phrase[i] == 'S')
        {
            phrase[i] = '7';
        }
        
        if (phrase[i] == 'T' || phrase[i] == 'U' || phrase[i] == 'V')
        {
            phrase[i] = '8';
        }
        
        if (phrase[i] == 'W' || phrase[i] == 'X' || phrase[i] == 'Y' || phrase[i] == 'Z')
        {
            phrase[i] = '9';
        }
        
        if (phrase[i] == '*' || phrase[i] == '#' || phrase[i] == '-')
        {
            dashes++;
        }
        else if (dashes > 0)
        {
            phrase[i - dashes] = phrase[i];
        }
    }

    phrase[strlen(phrase)-1] = '\0';
    
    printf("%s\n", phrase);
}

int main()
{
    char phrase[300];

    while (!feof(stdin))
    {
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", phrase);
        alterChars(phrase);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any tips will be valuable. You can [access the problem](https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2678) to see where the error is occurring. Anyway, it's on the last entry, at number 190. It is being printed 19, but in fact it should be printed 190, because the removal of characters should only occur when there are letters, or symbols.

**Examples**

Input: 333-PORTO
Output: 33376786

The problem:

Input: 190
Output: 19

Comment: Please do not assume that a non-English page provides info to StackOverflow users.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, for input "333-PORTO" I get output "33376786
3337678" in two lines. Not the stated output. The problem hence different than described. Please double check.

Comment: The statement `phrase[strlen(phrase)-1] = '\0';` will chop off the last 1 character regardless of number of dashes (or exhibit undefined behavior, i.e. a bug, if `strlen(phrase)==0`).  You want `phrase[i - dashes] = '\0'`.  Also, and this is subjective, but I think all those `if`s for the various letters would be clearer as one `switch` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your "generous" scanning, i.e. practically no expected syntax, you can simply loop while scanning is successful.

```
while (1==scanf(" %299[^\n]", phrase)) alterChars(phrase);
```

That fixes the problem with your while condition ( see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) ).

Then you want to read each line until either newline or terminator:

```
for (i = 0; phrase[i] != '\0' && phrase[i] != '\n'; i++)
```

And you want to force-terminate with respect to the dashes.

```
phrase[strlen(phrase)-dashes] = '\0';
```

and you get the desired output - and in only one line.... ;-)

The explanation is, if you always terminate as with 1 dash, then it works for 1 dash, fails by cutting too much for zero dashes and does other unwanted stuff for more than one dash, i.e. repeat the last few characters.
It is after all unrelated to "numeric only".

I have incorporated this good input by chux:

> `scanf(" %[^\n]s"` is bad as it has not width limit and 2) the s is pointless.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I'm making a mess while trying to remove special chars from the string. Could you please recommend me any resource to fix it?

Comment: I realised after editing and testing and improving, that I am now very close to the comment by @Perette. Please either believe me that this is my own, or accept the credits to Perette, who decided to comment instead of answering.

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]s"` is bad as it has not width limit and 2) the `s` is pointless.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good point. I will improve.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Better?

Comment: Oh dear, I do not really like working with scanf().